# Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix for tools:context

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, namespaces

Eclipse editor gives "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix" error for the following XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainMenuActivity" >
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is because `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` is missing. The code should look like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainMenuActivity" >
```

Answer (score 1):

add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to  your layout

and also note there should be only one namespace for your layout and it should be used in parent layout !

**chanage your code to**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainMenuActivity" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" to your code.