# change android text color

Tags: java, android, textcolor

I trying to change my text color by using below code.

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLefe="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"/>
```

However the compiler said **cannot resolve symbol @color/blue**. I refer to   http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/lesson-1-3-how-to-change-a-color-of-text-and-background-in-textview/ but why it's not working for me?

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  

    <resources>
        <color android:name="green">#00ff00</color>
        <color android:name="red">#FF0000</color>
        <color android:name="blue">#0000FF</color>
    </resources>
```

**Edited**

[image]

**Mainfest.java**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.project.project" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"

        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name =".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WorkDetailsTable">
            </activity>
        <activity android:name=".WorkForce">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ListDisplay">
            </activity>
        <activity android:name=".UpdatePage">
            </activity>

        <activity android:name=".UpdatePage2">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Do you have the blue color defined in your color.xml file?

Comment: my bad..miss out that part..thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to create color.xml file in values folder like in he image below
[image]

and in the file write

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
   <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
 </resources>
```

Comment: Attribute is missing the Android namespace

Comment: @Hoo just make sure that in your xml file you have added xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: @Hoo for reference have a look at => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301389/attribute-is-missing-the-android-namespace-prefix-for-toolscontext

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
   <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
 </resources>

Comment: @Hoo in your color.xml remove that linear layout.

Comment: so it is put under drawable or layout?

Comment: @Hoo i have edited your question kindly check it and replace your code with me that i have given in your question.

Comment: @Hoo not in drawable nither in layout put that code in color.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93092/discussion-between-hoo-and-moubeen-farooq-khan).

Comment: I create a colors.xml in layout and put all your code inside..but I seeing a red line underneath resources...Element resources doesn't has required....

Comment: @Hoo not in layout put it in values folder have a look at the image that i have provided in the answer.

Comment: ok, but I seeing a red line underneath the color...'name attribute should be defined....'

Comment: @Hoo can you post take the screenshot of that and post it here. also take the screen shot of file where you have created it.

Comment: @Hoo it is color.xml not colors.xml

Comment: Any difference? I have changed to color but the error still there

Comment: @Hoo change colors.xml to color.xml this is the difference. android studio does not know about colors.xml

Comment: @Hoo remove xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" form resousc tag

Comment: will the error came from mainfest? I have removed it and the error still there

Answer (score 3):

You need to define blue hex color in `values` directory in `colors.xml` file
Example of `colors.xml` file with blue color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: if I want to change background color, do I need to define in colors.xml? Or just for text color?

Comment: Attribute is missing the Android namespace